# HTML5 audio stream manipulation

Tags: html, audio-streaming

Hi do any of you gurus know how, or even if it is possible, to extract a snippet of an HTML5 audio stream, preferably by stating a start and stop time range.

To be precise, this is not the stream from a microphone input but the stream from an HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

Imagine the scenario that we have an audio file being streamed of 5 minutes length and we want to extract a portion of it starting from 1 minute and 15 seconds and ending at one minute and 32 seconds.

If this is indeed possible is it also possible to achieve this in the background without interrupting the current playback.

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated

Thank you